# Java : this alone in method

Tags: java, class, methods, this, redefinition

Hello everybody i'm currently learning java programming and I don't understand a part of code.
I searched a long time but I didn't found anything. Here is my code:

```
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {

  if (this == obj)
    return true;

  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
    return false;
    
  Ville other = (Ville) obj;

  return Objects.equals(other.getCategorie(), this.getCategorie()) &&
     Objects.equals(other.getNom(), this.getNom()) &&
     Objects.equals(other.getNombreHabitants(), this.getNombreHabitants()) &&
     Objects.equals(other.getNomPays(), this.getNomPays());
}
```

I don't understand two parts.
First:

```
if (this == obj)
```

I understand that we are trying to check something but I don't understand what?
And secondly :

```
Ville other = (Ville) obj;
```

I just don't understand what it does there is no trace of a Ville class named other. This is my first Question maybe I'm not clear.
Thank to all the people who will answer me :)

Comment: "`if (this == obj) return true;`" means "if an object is compared to itself, say they're equal". It would be an odd world if a thing were not equal to itself.

Comment: "there is no trace of a Ville class named other" this is declaring a variable.

Comment: okay we are comparing an object to itself but if we do that why there is other code ? To declare an object don't we need to say ```Ville example = new Ville(); ```

Comment: `new String("hello")` is equal to `new String("hello")`, but `new String("hello") != new String("hello")`. Things can be equal without being identical.

Comment: What is compared between these two String I don't really understand

Comment: let's say we each have an apple. They're both the same shade of green, they're the same size, weight, shininess etc. If you swapped our apples over, I would be none the wiser: they are to all intents and purposes interchangeable: they're *equal*. But they're not the same apple: they're two distinct things: they have different *identity*. In Java, you check for equality with `equals`, and identity with `==` (or `!=`). In terms of Strings, two Strings can have the same contents (the same characters in the same order) and thus are `equals`; but they're not the same object, so they're not `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  if (this == obj)
    return true;
```

This is the 1st check, it checks whether they are the same object (they allocate the same memory address). If this is `true`, it returns immediately, as they are, 100% sure, the same object.

If this isn't the case, it goes for the 2nd check:

```
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
    return false;
```

This checks whether they're the objects of the same class. If they are not, it returns `false` immediately.

If those two conditions aren't met, it goes for the deep-check.

```
  Ville other = (Ville) obj;

  return Objects.equals(other.getCategorie(), this.getCategorie()) &&
     Objects.equals(other.getNom(), this.getNom()) &&
     Objects.equals(other.getNombreHabitants(), this.getNombreHabitants()) &&
     Objects.equals(other.getNomPays(), this.getNomPays());
```

First it makes a cast to the type `Ville`, so the object `obj` (declared as `other` once casted) can call its methods (`getNom()`, `getNombreHabitants()`, etc). At this moment, it will return `true` if the selected parameters of the two `Ville`s are equal.

Answer (score 2):

So, this whole method is btw. an override of the [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method of Java's Object class.

```
if (this == obj)
```

compares the reference of the current instance with the given object. You can think of it as a pointer - so basically the pointer (reference) is showing to the same block of memory, thus they have to be same.

```
Ville other = (Ville) obj;
```

Here we cast the parameter `obj` to an `Object` of the class `Ville`. The previous if, which compared the `Class` of `this` and `obj` ensures that this cast won't throw a [`ClassCastException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html).

Due to the context, I'd assume you copied this out of a class named `Ville`.

Answer (score 1):

This method is designed to determine if the contents (or values held by) 2 objects are identical.

The first test (very fast) is to check if the caller and `obj` are in fact the same object. In this case there is no need to test that the contents are identical or if they are of the same class, because this is obvious, so you can immediately return `true`.

The next check is that the caller and `obj` are of the same class. If not, then there will be no point checking the contents. It is likely the methods to check the contents aren't generically known. So, exit `false`.

The remainder is about comparing the contents of the caller and `obj`. The cast to `Ville` is to expose the methods necessary to access the contents of `obj` so that these may be compared to the caller's contents.

Answer (score 0):

## Reference variables

Both `this` and `obj` are *reference variables*. They are not actually objects themselves, they lead us to an object whose contents live live elsewhere in memory. A references variable is a name that refers us to the actual object. A [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) is another technical name for this.

## Object

An object, or instance, is a chunk of memory laid out in a certain way to hold various pieces of data (state) along with some methods (behavior). The class is a template defining the layout of that object in memory.

For example, suppose we have a class named `Dog` that tracks each dog's name. So we might have a dog named "Boo". That fact is represented somewhere in memory.

We can have one or more reference variables referring (pointing) to that object. Those references variables can have an explicit name such as your `obj`, or an implicit name such as `this`.

[image]

## `==` with objects means "are both pointing to same object"

Your code:

```
if (this == obj)
```

…means “if the reference variable named 'this' and the reference variable 'obj' both happen to be pointing to the very same object living elsewhere in memory”.

The double EQUALS SIGN characters are used to signify equality. But equality with reference variables means equality in the sense of both pointers are pointing to the same place in memory. We are not comparing a pair of objects, we are comparing a pair of pointers.

This pointer business can make your brain hurt, as a newbie programmer. Do not try too hard. In Java especially, the syntax is such that in day-to-day work we do think of `this` or `obj` as being the dog named Boo. Occasionally ponder the point of pointers (see what I did there?), but do not worry about it now. You will find one day the concept just clicks into place in your mind, trust me.

FYI, in some languages such as [*C*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) or [*C++*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), a programmer can see the actual value of a pointer: a number, the number of a location in memory where the object lives. In Java, we never see that actual number, for the sake of security and simplicity. We just trust that a reference variable will lead us to the object we desire.

## Primitives differ

All this discussion refers to *reference variables*, dealing with objects.

Java is not fully [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) in that, besides objects, it has primitives. A primitive is a simple bit of data. A primitive variable actually does contain that data. So a primitive variable is *not* a reference variable, and is not a pointer. Like apples and oranges, very different.

If we compare primitive variables with `==`, we actually are comparing the content of the data.

```
int x = 5 ;
int y = 7 ;
boolean areEqual = ( x == y ) ;
```

That code above is comparing the numbers five and seven, examining their equality as numbers. No objects involved, no pointers, no jumping around in memory as discussed with object reference variables above.

Caveat: All this discussion is greatly over-simplified for the sake of teaching.